# Error: EventHandler "btnLogin_Clicked" with correct signature not found in type

Tags: c#, xamarin, ldap

I am trying to create authentication against LDAP in Xamarin. I have Main.xaml where I created simple login form 
(Entry Placeholder="*Password"  IsPassword="True" x:Name="login_password") with button (Button  Clicked ="btnLogin_Clicked"  Text="Sign in"  x:Name="btnLogin"). 
Main.xaml.cs contains the code for LDAP connection. There I check the credentials and try to bind.

Unfortunately I receive this error: "EventHandler 'btnLogin_Clicked' with correct signature not found in type 'Main.xaml'".

I spent so much time on this and still could not figure out what I am doing wrong. I will appreciate if anybody could help me with this or give me some advises with where I may search the answer.

My piece of code:

---

```
public void btnLogin_Clicked(object sender,string login_username, string login_password, System.EventArgs e)
    {


        string searchBase = "dc = it, dc = local";
        string searchFilter = "(amemberOf=ALL)";
        string ldapHost = "7777.. ";
        int ldapPort = 389;
        string loginDN = "dc = it, dc = local";

        /*if username or passworwd fields are empty show an error*/

        if (login_username is null || login_password is null)
        {
             DisplayAlert("Alert", "Please, enter your credentials", "OK");

        }
        else
        {
            /*creating an LDAP instance*/
            using (LdapConnection connection = new LdapConnection())

                /*here we create new ldap connection*/
                try
                {
                    /*connect function will creat socket connection to the server*/
                    connection.Connect(ldapHost, ldapPort);
                    connection.Bind(string.Format("{0}@{1}", loginDN, login_username), login_password);
                    LdapSearchQueue queue = connection.Search(searchBase,
                    LdapConnection.SCOPE_ONE, searchFilter, null, false, (LdapSearchQueue)
                    null, (LdapSearchConstraints)null);
                    LdapMessage message;

                    while ((message = queue.getResponse()) != null)
                    {
                        if (message is LdapSearchResult)
                        {
                            /*display message if connect*/
                             DisplayAlert("" ," logged in ", "OK ");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            /*if the message is not null but the login was failed*/
                            DisplayAlert("", "Login failed", "OK ");


                        }...
```

Answer (score 11):

a Button's event handler has the signature

```
public void btnLogin_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
```

you cannot just add extra parameters to the signature

Comment: thank you for your answer. Yes it helped. I do not receive the error although after putting my credentials I receive "Login failed". Do I miss something?

Comment: @kristonik Try to put an incorrect password, does it give the same "Login failed". Is there anything else in the Application output window?

Comment: so are async event handlers are off the table?

Comment: `async` is not part of the method signature, it's really just a hint to the C# compiler.  You can add it if your handler contains async code